# Emacs and gvim display no content on FreeBSD 10.2

Tags: freebsd, emacs, mate-desktop, gvim

I just installed FreeBSD 10.2 with the Mate desktop environment and most things seem to work. I have a problem with `emacs` and `gvim` though. Since the problem has the same symptoms with both editors, I suppose the cause is somewhere else.

In both editors, the content of the edit buffer is initially black, even if it contains text. If I click with the mouse on the window top bar and move it slightly, the content is repainted and looks good: fonts, colours, syntax highlighting are as expected. But as soon as I type something in the editor window, the content becomes black again.

In `gvim`, I also tried the following:

1. I open a file -> content is black
2. I move the editor window -> content is displayed
3. I jump to the end of the buffer with `G` -> content is black again

In `emacs` I opened `slime` and it had similar problems:

1. The buffer is initially black.
2. I move the editor window -> buffer is repainted, fonts and colours are good
3. I type something in the `slime` buffer -> buffer is black again

I tried to produce screenshots using `import` but, interestingly, the resulting images show the correct content of the editor windows, whereas the window on screen still has black buffers. It seems that the window contents are rendered correctly but the result is not displayed on the screen.

I have also tried out `gedit` and it works properly.

Both `emacs` and `vim` work properly in a text console.

The only explanation I can think of is that it might be an Xorg problem (missing or wrong repaint event or something like that) but I have no clue as to where I should look now. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I just found out that the problem disappears if in

```
System -> Preferences -> Windows -> General
```

I check the option "Enable software compositing window manager"

Note that I have this problem on FreeBSD only. On Debian Wheezy with Mate and "software compositing window manager" disabled, emacs and gvim work normally.

Comment: Just in case - is the result the same if you run `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @jimmij: Yes. Now the background is white but I cannot see what I type in the editor. If I move the window, the content is shown. As soon as I move the cursor over a line of text, the line disappears (becomes white).

Comment: The black background I talk about in the question comes from my `.emacs` file.